# JAX-RS NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

the method
of my jax-rs application:

```
@GET
@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List <Document> getDocumentList(@HeaderParam("Range") String headerRange) {
int [] range = getRangeFromHeader(headerRange);
return facade.listByRange(range);
}
```

working properly.
But If modifications to the:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDocumentList(@HeaderParam("Range") String headerRange) {
   int[] range = getRangeFromHeader(headerRange);
   return Response.ok(
          facade.listByRange(range))
         .header("Content-Range", getContentRangeStr(range)).build();
}
```

I receive an error

```
...NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response
object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/json...
```

Server Jboss 7.1.1

Please tell me what's wrong.

PS.sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is method return type of facade.listByRange ?

Comment: the method signature
    public List <T> listByRange (int [] range)
but the true type
List<Document>

Comment: This error occurs when I use the <jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below should do the trick.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDocumentList(@HeaderParam("Range") String headerRange) {
   int[] range = getRangeFromHeader(headerRange);
   return Response.ok(
        new GenericEntity<List<Document>>( (List<Document>)facade.listByRange(range))
         )
         .header("Content-Range", getContentRangeStr(range)).build();
}
```

The anonymous `GenericEntity` subclass is required to supply the correct type information (otherwise erased by the compiler) for the writer.

-- **EDIT**

The reason why your code worked using `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider` but not with `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider` resides on the fundamental difference between the two providers:

- the former (jackson) relies on a JavaBean model, discovering the properties of the objects to serialize, and needs no type information
- the latter (jettyson) relies on the JAXB annotations, so it needs the underlying type information, erased by the compiler.

Comment: sounds like magic to me, but it works. Thank you. And why the method works without wrapping (just Response.ok (facade.listByRange (range))) in the case of resteasy-jackson-provider?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a library as described here:

[Here is the solution](https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/severe-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-typeapplicationjson-type/)

> This means that you are missing a JSON library in your classpath. Jackson is one I’m using so adding this to your pom.xml will help:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Read more at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer