# Resteasy 3.0.9.Final NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure

Tags: java, jaxb, resteasy

When using RestEasy **3.0.9.Final and also 3.0.11.Final**, This error was thrown:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: [Lmodels.Person; of media type: application/json
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67)
```

I had read ELSEWHERE that it is because of Jaxb.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>          
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**I had ALSO tried this dependency instead of just ONLY jaxb**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>                
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Actually the code below was working previously WITHOUT error**:

```
@Path("/persons")
public class PersonController {
...
    @GET
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public Person[] get() {
        //log.info("Getting all Person");
        return database.currentList();
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    private String pid;
    private String name;
    public Person() {
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }
... // with other setters and getters also.
}
```

**Not too sure why suddenly it was not working now.**

Comment: I had also read this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613031/jax-rs-nomessagebodywriterfoundfailure

Comment: ALSO here:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-could-not-find-messagebodywriter-for-response-object-of-typexx-of-media-type-applicationxml/

Comment: If any like to help solve this issue, please download the sample project here, link will expire on June 10, 2015.:
https://www.hightail.com/download/bXBaTXRSSU9LVld4djlVag